# Video/image analysis to acquire distances between contours

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy, distance

New image: [test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lszR.jpg)

I'm trying to quantify the distance between two contours in a video of a microvessel (see snapshot)

Image analysis structure

[image: Image analysis structure]

Right now I'm only able to select for one contour (which is outlined) and I'm acquiring dimensions from this outline, but what I'd like to select for is the top and bottom contour of the structure and measure the distance (labeled with an orange line and A in the snapshot).

Any suggestions as to do this? My code for this video analysis is the following. Thanks for the help in advance!:

```
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import imutils
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils import perspective
from imutils import contours

videocapture = cv2.VideoCapture('RTMLV.mp4')

def safe_div(x,y):
    if y==0: return 0
    return x/y

def nothing(x):
    pass

def rescale_frame(frame, percent=100): #make the video windows a bit smaller
    width = int(frame.shape[1]*percent/100)
    height = int(frame.shape[0]*percent/100)
    dim = (width, height)
    return cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

if not videocapture.isOpened():
    print("Unable to open video")
    exit()

windowName="Vessel Tracking"

cv2.namedWindow(windowName)

# Sliders to adjust image

cv2.createTrackbar("Threshold", windowName, 75, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("Kernel", windowName, 5, 30, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("Iterations", windowName, 1, 10, nothing)

showLive=True
while(showLive):

    ret, frame=videocapture.read()
    frame_resize=rescale_frame(frame)
    if not ret:
        print("Cannot capture the frame")
        exit()

    thresh = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Threshold", windowName)
    ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(frame_resize, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    kern = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Kernel", windowName)
    kernel = np.ones((kern, kern), np.uint8) # square image kernel used for erosion

    itera=cv2.getTrackbarPos("Iterations", windowName)
    dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, kernel, iterations=itera)
    erosion = cv2.erode(dilation, kernel, iterations=itera) #refines all edges in the binary image

    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(erosion, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    closing = cv2.cvtColor(closing, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # find contours with simple approximation cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE

    closing = cv2.cvtColor(closing,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    cv2.drawContours(closing, contours, -1, (128,255,0), 1)

    # focus on only the largest outline by area
    areas = [] #list to hold all areas

    for contour in contours:
      ar = cv2.contourArea(contour)
      areas.append(ar)

    max_area = max(areas)
    max_area_index = areas.index(max_area)  # index of the list element with largest area

    cnt = contours[max_area_index - 1] # largest area contour is usually the viewing window itself, why?

    cv2.drawContours(closing, [cnt], 0, (0,0,255), 1)

    def midpoint(ptA, ptB): 
      return ((ptA[0] + ptB[0]) * 0.5, (ptA[1] + ptB[1]) * 0.5)

    # compute the rotated bounding box of the contour
    orig = frame_resize.copy()
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
    box = np.array(box, dtype="int")

    # order the points in the contour such that they appear
    # in top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
    # order, then draw the outline of the rotated bounding
    # box
    box = perspective.order_points(box)
    cv2.drawContours(orig, [box.astype("int")], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

    # loop over the original points and draw them
    for (x, y) in box:
      cv2.circle(orig, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # unpack the ordered bounding box, then compute the midpoint
    # between the top-left and top-right coordinates, followed by
    # the midpoint between bottom-left and bottom-right coordinates
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = box
    (tltrX, tltrY) = midpoint(tl, tr)
    (blbrX, blbrY) = midpoint(bl, br)

    # compute the midpoint between the top-left and top-right points,
    # followed by the midpoint between the top-right and bottom-right
    (tlblX, tlblY) = midpoint(tl, bl)
    (trbrX, trbrY) = midpoint(tr, br)

    # draw the midpoints on the image
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(blbrX), int(blbrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(trbrX), int(trbrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)

    # draw lines between the midpoints
    cv2.line(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), (int(blbrX), int(blbrY)),(255, 0, 255), 1)
    cv2.line(orig, (int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), (int(trbrX), int(trbrY)),(255, 0, 255), 1)
    cv2.drawContours(orig, [cnt], 0, (0,0,255), 1)

    # compute the Euclidean distance between the midpoints
    dA = dist.euclidean((tltrX, tltrY), (blbrX, blbrY))
    dB = dist.euclidean((tlblX, tlblY), (trbrX, trbrY))

    # compute the size of the object
    P2M4x = 1.2
    P2M10x = 3.2
    P2M20x = 6
    pixelsPerMetric = P2M10x # Pixel to micron conversion
    dimA = dA / pixelsPerMetric
    dimB = dB / pixelsPerMetric

    dimensions = [dimA, dimB]

    # draw the object sizes on the image
    cv2.putText(orig, "{:.1f}um".format(dimA), (int(tltrX - 15), int(tltrY - 10)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(orig, "{:.1f}um".format(dimB), (int(trbrX + 10), int(trbrY)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    # compute the center of the contour
    M = cv2.moments(cnt)
    cX = int(safe_div(M["m10"],M["m00"]))
    cY = int(safe_div(M["m01"],M["m00"]))

    # draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
    cv2.circle(orig, (cX, cY), 5, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    cv2.putText(orig, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    cv2.imshow(windowName, orig)
    cv2.imshow('', closing)
    if cv2.waitKey(30)>=0:
        showLive=False

videocapture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please attach the source image.

Answer (score 0):

Edits have been made to this answer in reponse to the new test image that was added to the post.

I was unable to segment the blood vessel in the test image using the code that you uploaded. I segmented the image by using manual annotation and the GrabCut algorithm.

[image: manual segmentation]

This is the code that I used for the manual segmentation:

```
import cv2, os, numpy as np
import time
# Plot with Matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img_path = '/home/stephen/Desktop/0lszR.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img = img[420:1200, :]
h,w,_ = img.shape
mask = np.zeros((h,w), np.uint8)
mask[:] = 2
src = img.copy()
h,w,_ = img.shape
drawing = src.copy()

# Mouse callback function
global k, px, py

k = 0
px, py = 0,0

def callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global k, px, py
    print(x,y, k, px, py)
    if k == 115: # 's' for sure background
        if px+py!=0:            
            cv2.line(img, (x,y), (px, py), (255,255,0), 8)
            cv2.line(mask, (x,y), (px, py), 0, 8)
    if k == 116: # 't' for sure foreground
        if px+py!=0:            
            cv2.line(img, (x,y), (px, py), (0,255,255), 8)
            cv2.line(mask, (x,y), (px, py), 1, 8)  
        else: print(px, py)
    px, py = x,y
    #if k != 115 or 116: px, py =  0,0
cv2.namedWindow('img')
cv2.setMouseCallback('img', callback)
while k != 27:
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    k_temp = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k_temp!=-1: k = k_temp
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After I had found the segmented image, I used the function `np.nonzero()` to find the tops and bottoms of the columns:

[image: finding width]

This is the code that I used to find the width:

```
# Initialize parameters for the GrabCut algorithm
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

# Apply GrabCut
out_mask = mask.copy()
out_mask, _, _ = cv2.grabCut(src,out_mask,None,bgdModel,fgdModel,1,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
out_mask = np.where((out_mask==2)|(out_mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
# Open the mask to fill in the holes
out_img = src*out_mask[:,:,np.newaxis]
flip_mask = cv2.flip(out_mask, 0)

# Find the distances
distances = []
for col_num in range(src.shape[1]-1):
    col = out_mask[:, col_num:col_num+1]
    flip_col = flip_mask[:, col_num:col_num+1]
    top = np.nonzero(col)[0][0]
    bottom = h-np.nonzero(flip_col)[0][0]
    if col_num % 12 == 0:
        cv2.line(drawing, (col_num, top), (col_num, bottom), (234,345,34), 4)
    distances.append(bottom-top)

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,3, sharex=True)
axarr[0,0].imshow(src)
axarr[0,1].imshow(out_mask)
axarr[0,2].imshow(drawing)
axarr[1,0].imshow(img)
axarr[1,1].imshow(out_img)
axarr[1,2].plot(distances)

axarr[0,0].set_title("Source")
axarr[0,1].set_title('Mask from GrabCut')
axarr[0,2].set_title('Widths')
axarr[1,0].set_title('Manual Annotation')
axarr[1,1].set_title('GrabCut Mask')
axarr[1,2].set_title('Graph of Width')

axarr[0,0].axis('off')
axarr[0,1].axis('off')
axarr[1,0].axis('off')
axarr[1,1].axis('off')
axarr[1,2].axis('off')
axarr[0,2].axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for sharing your answer. When testing your code with one of my sample images, I get a traceback error to line 29, left = max(top_points[0][0], bottom_points[0][0])... this is the error I get: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @aceofshades09 I'm not sure what is going wrong. Can you attach your source image (add it to the question)?

Comment: Yes, added to top of the post... "test image"